# AVAudioPlayer run in background but doesn't receive RemoteControlEvent

Tags: ios, background, avaudioplayer

I want to refine my question, The player receive remote control event only if the user press home button in the player view controller.
If he press play and than go wondering inside the app and press home button, The music still playing but nothing happened in term of remoteControlEvent.
I'm sure I'm missing something :|

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Register for background

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to subclass UIWindow or make Category for UIApplication

I had the same issue.

[remoteControlReceivedWithEvent not Called in appDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862317/remotecontrolreceivedwithevent-not-called-in-appdelegate)